# This set of code keep on looping and looping. May I know how to stop looping?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am using this code to plot one column by column graph and it works. However I am having a problem. The window of the first column graph plot came out, and when I close it, the second column graph plot came out next. Once I close it, once again, the first column graph plot came out again, close it then second come out, close it then first one again. It keeps going through this continuous loop non stop. Does anyone knows how to stop this loop? Is there any error on my code?

file_path = ("C://Users/RichardStone/Pycharm/Project/train_data.csv")

df = pd.read_csv(file_path)

for column in df.columns:

```
print(df.iloc[:, [1]])

plt.figure('Train data: Jitter (Local)')

plt.title('Feature: Jitter (Local)')

plt.plot(df.iloc[:, [1]])

plt.show()
```

print(df.iloc[:, [2]])

```
plt.figure('Train data: Jitter (local, absolute)')

plt.title('Feature: Jitter (local, absolute)')

plt.plot(df.iloc[:, [2]])

plt.show()
```

Comment: Please format the code in your question, select it and type `ctrl-k`. Make sure the indentation is correct.
.. [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: Sorry I am quite new to stackoverflow. When i select it and type ctrl-k, only the google search bar of my browser came down.

Comment: First you have to [edit] your question, then select the code and type `ctrl-k`.

Answer (score 0):

Well your graph plotting is inside the for loop.This is why it is keep showing graph for times your data length is. Once data is read by script, Indent back and then show the graph

Comment: Do you have any idea how to stop the loop? Like is there any code I can add in that can help me stop the loop? Like do i have to type something at the end or something?